# Solving differential equation by variable separation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:
$$ y-x \frac {dy}{dx}=a\left(y^2+\frac {dy}{dx}\right)$$
I have started like this:
$$ y-x \frac {dy}{dx}=ay^2+a\frac {dy}{dx}\\
\implies y-ay^2=(x+a)\frac {dy}{dx}\\$$
But I can't understand what to do next..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$−^2=(+)\dfrac{}{}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{y-ay^2}=\dfrac{dx}{x+a}$$
$$\implies \left(\dfrac{a}{1-ay}+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)~dy=\dfrac{dx}{x+a}$$
Integrating,
$$-\ln(1-ay)+\ln y=\ln (x+a)+\ln c$$
$$\dfrac{y}{1-ay}=c(x+a)$$where $c$ is integrating constant.

Comment: Thanks for helping 

Comment: Do you know, the question that you are posting here are just basic courses of differential equation ?

Comment: Yes I know...I am just studying the differential equations

Comment: Good, try to understand the question and the language of your book, discuss your problem with your friends, teachers. It will be better for you.

Comment: What books are you using for differential equation ?

Comment: "Higher Engineering Mathematics " by B.S.Grewal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103295/discussion-between-nmasanta-and-ankita-pal).

Answer (score 0):

I would try re-arranging from there further until you get:

$\frac{1}{a+x} = \frac{1}{y-ay^2} \frac{dy}{dx}$

From there integrate the RHS with respect to x and the LHS with respect to y:

$\int \frac{1}{a+x} dx = \int \frac{1}{y-ay^2} dy$

This evaluates to:

$ln(x+a) = ln(y) - ln(1-ay) + C$

Which can be simplified by taking an exponential of each side.

$x+a = K\frac{y}{1-ay}$

Where $K$ is a constant (the exponential of $C$).

I don't know what form of answer you were hoping for - but hopefully this helps!

Edit - apologies, misused log/power rules with constants for a moment there!

Edit2 - this can simplify to:

$y=\frac{x+a}{K+a(x+a)}$

Comment: The answer is $$(1-ay)(a+x)=cy$$ and you got the same answer...thanks for helping 

Comment: Fantastic - happy to have helped!